# beforeunload fired only on specific occasions

Tags: javascript

I have a workflow there I want an alert fired when user tries to close browser tab or browser itself.

I use this code for this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may will not be saved.";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

The problem is that there is specific button and when you press on it you are supposed to leave the site without confirmations.

How such logics could be handled in this case?

Comment: You can check if the event comes from a specific target. `event.target`

Comment: I am not sure if a browser will provide you information on whether user closes tab or navigates away. It sounds like sort of private information not related to your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(e.target == /add your button/)

check for target within the handler

Comment: This was actually was that simple. Thanks.